# I want to loop a specified number of times and display the array if any of the conditions are met

Tags: javascript

If there is the following data and loops the specified number of times (example: 6 times) and number = n at the nth time, the contents of number are displayed in console.log, if there is no data of number = n I want to do "no data". In this case, should I use the for statement or map?

In Python, I used Pandas to fill in the data, but how can I implement this in JavaScript?
I would appreciate it if you could tell me how to do this in JavaScript.

```
item = [{
    "id": 1,
    "number": 2
},
{
    "id": 2,
    "number": 3
}
]
```

In this case↓

```
no data
2
3
no data
no data
no data
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
item = [{
    "id": 1,
    "number": 2
},
{
    "id": 2,
    "number": 3
}
]
n = 6
const obj = {}

item.forEach((data) => {
        obj[data.number] = true 
})

for (let i=1;i<=n;i++) {
        if (obj[i])
                console.log(i);
        else
                console.log("no data")
}
```